# How can a program have a high virtual byte count while the private bytes are relatively low on Windows 32-bit?

Tags: windows, performance, memory, memory-management

I'm trying to get a better understanding of how Windows, 32-bit, calculates the virtual bytes for a program. I am under the impression that Virtual Bytes (VB) are the measure of how much of the user address space is being used, while the Private Bytes (PB) are the measure of actual committed and reserved memory on the system.

In particular, I have a server program I am monitoring which, when under heavy usage, will climb up to the 3GB limit for VBs. Around the same time the PB climb as well, but then quickly drop down to around 1 GB as the usage drops. The PB tend to then stay low, around the 1 GB mark, but the VB stay up around the 3 GB mark. I do not have access to the source code, so I am just using the basic Windows performance counters to monitor all of this. From a programming point of view, what memory concept do I not understand that makes this all possible? Is there a good reference to learn more about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your reporting is most likely being caused by the process heap.  There are two pieces to a memory allocation in Windows.  The first piece is the continuous address space in your application for the memory to accessed through.  On a 32 bit system not running the /3GB switch all your allocations must come out of the lower 2 GB of user address space.  The second piece of the memory allocation is the actually memory for the allocation.  This can be either RAM or part of the page file system on the hard disk.  The OS handles moving allocations between RAM and the page file system in the background.

Most likely your application is using a Windows heap to handle all memory allocations.  When a heap is created is reserves 1 MB of address space for the memory it will allocate.  Until it actually needs memory associated with this address space no physical memory is actually used.  If the heap needs more memory than 1 MB it uses a doubling algorithm to reserve more address space, and then commits physical memory when it needs it.  The important thing to note is that once a heap reserves address space it never releases it.

Personally I found the following books and chapters useful when trying to understand memory management.

Advanced Windows Debugging - Chapter 6 This book has the most detailed look into the heap I have seen.

Windows Internals - Chapter 7 This book adds a bit of information not found in Advanced Windows Debugging; however, it does not give as good an overview.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you have a garbage collector that's only kicking in once the memory pressure hits 1/3 (1 GB out of 3 GB).

As for the VB - don't worry! It's virtual! Honestly, nothing's been allocated, nothing's been committed. Focus on your private bytes - your real allocations.

Answer (score 0):

There is such a thing as "Virtual Memory". It's a rather non-OS-specific concept in computer science. Microsoft has also [written](http://msdn.microsoft.com/lv-lv/library/aa366912(en-us,VS.85).aspx) about Windows implementation of the thing.

A long story short, in Windows you can ask to reserve some memory without actually allocating any physical memory. It's like making some memory addresses reserved for future use. When you really need the memory, you allocate it physically (aka "commit" it).

I haven't needed to use this feature myself, so I don't know how it's used in real life programs, but I know it's there. I think the idea might be something like preserving pointers to some memory address and allocating the memory when needed, without having to change what the pointers actually point to.

Answer (score 0):

Windows is notorious for having a variety of types of memory allocations, some of which are supersets of others.  You've mentioned Private Bytes and Virtual Bytes.  Private bytes, as you know, refers to memory allocated specifically to your process.  Virtual bytes includes private bytes, as well as any shared memory, reserved memory, etc.

Even though in real life you only need to be concerned with private bytes and perhaps shared memory (Windows handles the rest, anyways), the Virtual Bytes count is often what users (and evaluators of your software) see and interpret as the memory usage of your process.

Answer (score 0):

A good and up-to-date reference on the subject is the book titled Windows Via C/C++ by Jeffrey Richter, you should look for Chapter 13: "Windows Memory Architecture".